# Displaying an array as a string in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to display an array as a string which is seperated by commas in react native. This is my code.

```
let currentWorkout = this.props.currentWorkout;
// tools is an array. want to display it as valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree etc.
    let tools = JSON.stringify(currentWorkout.tools);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WorkoutDetail
          workout={this.props.currentWorkout}
          workoutImage={currentWorkout.workoutImage}
          onPressWorkout={() => alert("CONTINUE WORKOUT")}
        />
        <View style={styles.workoutInfo}>
          <KeyValueText header="Tools" value={tools} /> ////
        </View>
      </View>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
let tools = currentWorkout.tools.join(', ');
```

instead of `JSON.stringify` and I think you'll got the results you want.

Check the [documentation for the join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: Thanks Khriz. But when I used this, it says, currentWorkout is undefined.

Comment: Well then currentWorkout.tools is not an array, you should check ```this.props.currentWorkout``` because you are passing no props to the component

Comment: It worked after this Khriz. 
let tools = currentWorkout.tools 
      ? currentWorkout.tools.join(", ")
      : "";

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much